# A pascal triangle-like puzzle

Tags: puzzle, pattern-recognition

[image]

I found this challenging maths puzzle meant for primary 1 (6-7 years old) students in a local school and I've wracked my brains but to my shame can't seem to find any solution. Is there one?

Edit: I can't seem to embed the picture properly so I'll try to type the puzzle out:

```
    1
   2 3
  3 4 4
 2 1 _ 2
2 3 _ _ 2
```

The task is to discover the pattern and fill in the missing numbers.

Comment: Well one can find many patterns...If $a = 10$ and $b=5, c=6$, then for any row, the difference between the sum of the second to the last (left to right) equals the sum of all element of the row above.